# My Samsung Galaxy S3 keeps on restarting every time

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Why does my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone keep on restarting every time. It's getting worse. Now even without touching the power button it starts by itself. What might cause this and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restore your phone (factory reset).This may be due to auto running of an application which is consuming your memory .